# ActiveAdmin & active_enum gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, activeadmin

I have the following values using the active_enum gem:

**initializers/active_enum.rb**

```
ActiveEnum.define do
  # defines Syllabus
  enum(:syllabus) do
    value :id => 1, :name => 'Trinity Rock & Pop'
    value :id => 2, :name => 'Trinity Guildhall'
    value :id => 3, :name => 'ABRSM'
  end
end
```

**models/lesson.rb**

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  enumerate :syllabus
end
```

**admin/lessons.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Lesson do
  index do
    column :syllabus
  end
end
```

The ActiveAdmin index column shows the syllabus `:id`, how do I get it to show the syllabus `:name`?

I've tried

```
column :syllabus, :name
column :syllabus_name
column :syllabus.name
```

CRUD with AA works as intended with `:names`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Might not be the best way to do the job but it's simple and it works:

**initializers/active_enum.rb**

```
ActiveEnum.define do
  # defines Syllabus
  enum(:syllabus) do
    value :id => 'Trinity Rock & Pop', :name => 'Trinity Rock & Pop'
    value :id => 'Trinity Guildhall', :name => 'Trinity Guildhall'
    value :id => 'ABRSM', :name => 'ABRSM'
  end
end
```

by changing the :id to match the :name, ActiveAdmin index columns displays the intended string.

**Note:**

- using

**initializers/active_enum.rb**

```
config.use_name_as_value = true
```

saves the value :id in the database but activeadmin displays value :name as "empty".

- Activeadmin filter **:as => :select** doesn't work. **:as => :search** works without issues.

Comment: it is definitely not the best way. it is not necessary here to make code not DRY with value id and name duplication

Comment: i'm curious, will the active_enum gem work just as well with only the :id without the :name? The gem's readme indicates that one can have implicit :id but the :name must always be present. If someone would like to experiment and report their findings please do. I have spent enough time on this issue and have to move on.

Comment: NOTE: Active_enum does NOT work without the value's :name. So there's no way to make the values DRY thus far.

Answer (score 2):

according to AA Docs http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html (4th snippet) and [ActiveEnum Documentation](https://github.com/adzap/active_enum#attribute-value-lookup)

you can get the name in this way:

```
column('Name') {|lesson| lesson.syllabus(:name)}
```

Comment: hmm, doesnt work. also, I cant find any reference to your code in the tutorial.

Comment: look into 4th code snippet in reference: `column 'Title'...` In general case it is a way to display the result of any method (or attribute value) in AA column for each instance in scope... you have scope of objects for each one of them you have to declare the method to get the name. as far as i understood what your object is, the method to get the name is `s[:name]`... try other valid method to get the name of instance if i was wrong in this part

Comment: I've copied your code verbatim, received the error 'expected ; or end of line'. I have no doubt that you're close to the mark however, and will try and get your code to work when i have the time. Thank you so much for trying to help.

Comment: awh... `{...}` and `do |..| ... ;end` not the same ... corrected my answer again - must be correct! (changed `column 'Name' => column('Name')`)

Comment: Sorry mate, the amended code is syntactically correct, and i wish it works, however the ActiveAdmin index column still shows the value '2' as opposed to 'Trinity Guildhall'. I'm as frustrated as you are (if not more so due to hours spent and the fact that values are stored as strings rather than integers) but i'll have to accept my own answer as it's the only one that works thus far. Many thanks for trying to help brother!